# ( Vue.js ) Why button with $emit doesn't work?

Tags: vue.js

The problem is when i press button ( `<button @click="$emit('remove-todo',task.id)">` ) method *removeTodo* doesn't work and doesn't output 'd' in console, in this case. In general, i'm trying to realize button which can delete my todos from list. i'm newbie in Vue and maybe that's why i made that silly mistake.

***There are no error messages in console***

**Code (Home.vue)**

```html
<template>
   <div>
       <h1>Todo List</h1>
       <table v-if="tasks.length">
           <thead>
               <th>#</th>
               <th>Title</th>
               <th>Description</th>
           </thead>
           <tbody>
               <tr 
               v-for="(task, idx) of tasks"
               :key="task.id"
               >
               <td>{{ idx + 1 }}</td>
               <td>{{ task.title }}</td>
               <td>{{ task.description }}</td>
               <td class="close">
                   <button @click="$emit('remove-todo',task.id)" <!-- This button doesn't work -->
                            v-on:remove-todo="removeTodo"
                   ><i class="fas fa-times"></i></button>
               </td>
               </tr>
           </tbody>
       </table>
       <p v-else>No tasks for today.Create a new one</p>
   </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    computed:{
        tasks(){
            return this.$store.getters.tasks
        }
    },
    methods:{
        removeTodo(){
            console.log("d")
        }
    }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
h1{
    text-align: center;
}
table{
    display: table;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    background-color: rgba(1, 120, 26, 0.3);
    position: relative; 
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    border-radius: 10px; 
       
}
table thead{
    font-size: 25px;

}

table th{
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}
table th:last-child{
    border-right: none;
}
table td{
    width:15rem;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    color: white;
    border-top:2px solid black;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}
table td:last-child{
    border-right: none;
}

.close{
    width: 1rem;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.close button{
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #FF5050;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: #353535;
}
</style>
```

**App.vue**

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <Navbar />
  <router-view />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Navbar from '@/components/Navbar'
export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    Navbar
  }
}
</script>

<style>

#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
body{
  background-color:#444444;
}
</style>
```

**main.js**

```html
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'


Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

**I will be very grateful if you can help me to solve this problem**

Answer (score 0):

You can just do:

```
<button @click="removeTodo(task.id)"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></button>
```

the $emit() will be emitting the removeTodo in the parent component if you would have one.

Comment: Hooray, it works correctly. Thank you so much. I will know about emitting in the future :)